# Airflow: unix user from run_as_user parameter doesn't know airflow command

Tags: python, linux, bash, airflow, impersonation

I would like to run my Airflow DAG under a different user. Therefore I have added the run_as_user parameter to the DAGs arguments:

```
args = {
        'owner': 'airflow',
        'run_as_user' : 'bart',
        'start_date': airflow.utils.dates.days_ago(1),
        'retries': 0,
}

dag = DAG(
     dag_id = 'sqoop_owner_dwhd_layermodel_test2',
     default_args = args,
     schedule_interval = '0 9 * * *',
     catchup = False,
)
```

However, when running the DAG logs tell me:

```
[2021-09-07 09:20:53,728] {base_task_runner.py:134} INFO - Running: ['sudo', '-E', '-H', '-u', 'bart', 'airflow', 'tasks', 'run', 'sqoop_owner_dwhd_layermodel_test2', 'BL_SBL_AR_X_AR_HIST', '2021-08-02T09:00:00+00:00', '--job-id', '6037', '--pool', 'default_pool', '--raw', '--subdir', 'DAGS_FOLDER/dag_folder_datalab/sqoop_owner_dwhd_layermodel_test2.py', '--cfg-path', '/tmp/tmpss31q_to', '--error-file', '/tmp/tmptnrsji_5']
[2021-09-07 09:20:53,760] {base_task_runner.py:114} INFO - Job 6037: Subtask BL_SBL_AR_X_AR_HIST sudo: airflow: command not found
```

BTW, the worker journal tells me something a little different:

```
sudo[121552]:  airflow : command not allowed ; TTY=unknown ; PWD=/ ; USER=bart; COMMAND=airflow tasks run sqoop_owner_dwhd_layermodel_test2 BL_SBL_AR_X_AR_HIST 2021-08-02T09:00:00+00:00 --job-id 6037 --pool default_pool --raw --subdir DAGS_FOLDER/dag_folder_datalab/sqoop_owner_dwhd_layermodel_test2.py --cfg-path /tmp/tmpss31q_to --error-file /tmp/tmptnrsji_5
```

The command indeed is not found when testing the following directly on the server under the Airflow user: `sudo -u bart airflow info`
But a full references to `sudo -u bart /var/lib/airhome/airflow_env_dev/bin/airflow info` does work. I have added an `airflow` alias in both the `.bashrs` and the `.bash_profile` script, but still the `airflow` command is not found. I have also added the above reference to `PATH` and activated the environment for the unix user.

I would assume that I would be fairly simple to make the airflow commands available for my unix user. What am I doing wrong or what else can I try?

Comment: can you link /var/lib/airhome/airflow_env_dev/bin/airflow to /usr/local/bin ?